# Align multiple elements across bootstrap columns in the same row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to horizontally align multiple items across two columns within the same row in bootstrap. An example HTML Code can be found below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>Short Heading</h1>
        <p>Some super long content that will push the button far downward so that it will certainly not align with the next column anymore</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>Super long Heading that requires 2 rows</h1>
        <p>Some short content</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6pYhx/689/

Within the example, I would like to have 2 conditions

1. The header, p and button elements should be on the same horizontal height. In my example the right header is two rows, therefore the right p element is one row lower than the left p
2. If the screen size shrinks, all elements of column 1 should be right below each other, followed by all elements of column 2 -> I tried to solve it by having multiple rows, but then you'd have header 1, header 2, p 1, p 2, ... Instead I would like to have header 1, p 1, button 1, followed by header 2, p 2, button 2

Any ideas how to solve it with CSS?

Comment: so whats the problem? is doing exactly what you want

Comment: `The header, p and button elements should be on the same horizontal height` I am not clear with this point

Comment: If you look closely at my example, you will notice that the header, p and button elements are not on the same height. The right header is two lines, therefore the right p is one row lower than the left etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have three solutions.

1. **Use flexbox** at `media >= 768px`.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .make-it-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex-item-1 { order: 1; }
  .flex-item-2 { order: 2; }
  .flex-item-3 { order: 3; }
  .flex-item-4 { order: 4; }
  .flex-item-5 { order: 5; }
  .flex-item-6 { order: 6; }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Flexbox</h2>
  <div class="row make-it-flex">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 flex-item-1"><div class="well">Header 1</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 flex-item-3"><div class="well">Paragraph 1<br>has three lines<br>it's true</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 flex-item-5"><div class="well">Button 1</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 flex-item-2"><div class="well">Header 2<br>has two lines</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 flex-item-4"><div class="well">Paragraph 2</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 flex-item-6"><div class="well">Button 2<br>has two lines</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/uuLqokhm/

---

2. Duplicate data and **make two layouts** for different screen sizes.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container visible-xs">
  <h2>Columns</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><div class="well">Header 1</div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><div class="well">Paragraph 1<br>has three lines<br>it's true</div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><div class="well">Button 1</div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><div class="well">Header 2<br>has two lines</div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><div class="well">Paragraph 2</div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><div class="well">Button 2<br>has two lines</div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container hidden-xs"> 
  <h2>Lines</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><div class="well">Header 1</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><div class="well">Header 2<br>has two lines</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><div class="well">Paragraph 1<br>has three lines<br>it's true</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><div class="well">Paragraph 2</div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="line-3" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><div class="well">Button 1</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><div class="well">Button 2<br>has two lines</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/cjs1q42m/

---

3. **Add the script** and transmit data from one layout to another.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Columns</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div id="column-1" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 column-1 line-1"><div class="well">Header 1</div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 column-1 line-2"><div class="well">Paragraph 1<br>has three lines<br>it's true</div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 column-1 line-3"><div class="well">Button 1</div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div id="column-2" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 column-2 line-1"><div class="well">Header 2<br>has two lines</div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 column-2 line-2"><div class="well">Paragraph 2</div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 column-2 line-3"><div class="well">Button 2<br>has two lines</div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container"> 
  <h2>Lines</h2>
  <div id="line-1" class="row">
  </div>
  <div id="line-2" class="row">
  </div>
  <div id="line-3" class="row">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var idColumn1 = $('#column-1');
  var idColumn2 = $('#column-2');
  var idLine1 = $('#line-1');
  var idLine2 = $('#line-2');
  var idLine3 = $('#line-3');

  var classColumn1 = $('.column-1');
  var classColumn2 = $('.column-2');
  var classLine1 = $('.line-1');
  var classLine2 = $('.line-2');
  var classLine3 = $('.line-3');

  checkLayout();
  
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    checkLayout();
  });
  
  function checkLayout() {
    var classSm6 = 'col-sm-6';
    if (( window.innerWidth <= 768 ) && classColumn1.hasClass(classSm6)) {
      // console.info( "resize to xs" );
      classColumn1.appendTo(idColumn1).removeClass(classSm6);
      classColumn2.appendTo(idColumn2).removeClass(classSm6);
    } else if (( window.innerWidth > 768 ) && !classLine1.hasClass(classSm6)) {
      // console.info( "resize to sm" );
      classLine1.appendTo(idLine1).addClass(classSm6);
      classLine2.appendTo(idLine2).addClass(classSm6);
      classLine3.appendTo(idLine3).addClass(classSm6);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/cjwc6uev/

Comment: Thanks, this solves it! Nevertheless I am not a big fan of code repetition, and having to write a script for this kind of simple design seems outrageous to me (can't believe bootstrap does not have a simple built-in solution for this). If you don't mind, I would like to wait a 1-2 more days for some more answers before I mark this question as complete.

Comment: @Ruehri I also try to avoid repetitions and scripts. I'll just be happy if there exists a solution without their participation.

Comment: @Ruehri I'va aded a solution by flexbox to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want them to be centered in the columns? You could use text-center class on each column.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
```

If you want them vertically centered, there are a few ways to do it. I recently had this issue and we changed display to table-cell and used the vertical-align: middle; in CSS ([example here](http://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/same-height-bootstrap-columns)). Or you can use [flexbox](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/), but it doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: No sorry, probably I have not explained well enough. I would like to align the p and button elements horizontally. In my example the right header is two rows, therefore the right p element is one row lower than the left p

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying? Make the preview screen bigger to see the result if you are testing it in jsfiddle:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="col-md-3">Short Heading</h1>
        <p class="col-md-7">Some super long content that will push the button far downward so that it will certainly not align with the next column anymore</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary  class="col-md-2"">Button</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
          <h1 class="col-md-3">Super long Heading that requires 2 rows</h1>
          <p class="col-md-7">Some short content</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-2">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

also, you can play with the inner columns to make them the right size for your needs, but this is, as you needed, on the same row. I made this for medium or wider screens and on small screens it will be defaulted to the normal behaviour of having them one under another, but again, you can play with that by changing the `md` part or adding more classes like `col-xs-... col-sm-... col-lg-...`

here's how that looks:
[image]

you can also try this if you want your content to be horizontally aligned as well, it is a bit tricky but it works:

https://plnkr.co/edit/s01bZi2OJc8xm2QlKuII?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, I just tried out and it comes out as a mess (even after fixing the double "class =" in the first button), not sure what exactly your code does...

Comment: oops, my bad with the class but, describe "a mess", they are aligned horizontally quite well on my screen. The only problem is because the font is to big the content within them doesn't look great indeed. And again, you can play with those classes to make the heading area bigger or smaller, and same for the content and the button.

Comment: Sorry, was probably not fully clear in my question. Understand what you understood from my question now... It is not having all elements on the same height, but the headers on the same height, the <p>s on the same height, and the buttons on the same height. See Gleb's answer, he has a working solution